# How to put a fade transition in this spoiler?

Tags: css, transition

I want to put a fade transition in my spoiler, using CSS. Here is the code:

HTML:

```
<button style="position:absolute;left:600px;top:20px" type="button" onclick="if(document.getElementById('spoiler') .style.display=='none') {document.getElementById('spoiler') .style.display=''}else{document.getElementById('spoiler') .style.display='none'}">See the phrases</button>
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='style/spoiler.css'/>
<div id="spoiler" style="display:none;position:absolute;left:600px;top:50px"> 
<desc1>&nbsp;My phrases:</desc1>
<desc2><ul><li>First phrase</li>
</ul><ul><li>Second phrase</li></ul>
</des2>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
  #spoiler
{
    background:#FCFB8B;
    width:280px;
    height:200px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px #1f325d;
    -o-box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px #1f325d;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px #1f325d;
    -ms-box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px #1f325d;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px #1f325d;
}

#spoiler desc1

{
   font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
   font-size:18px;
   color:#FA4646;
}

#spoiler desc2
{
   font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
   font-size:16px;
   color:#000000;
   position:absolute;
   top:10px;
   left:-15px;
}
```

Well, I tried to put this code in ID spoiler, but it did not work. Can anyone help me?

```
-webkit-transition: all .8s ease-in;
-moz-transition: all .8s ease-in;
-o-transition: all .8s ease-in;
-ms-transition: all .8s ease-in;
```

I tried with hover, and worked, but i need automatically, when the button is pressed, the transition. How I can do this?
Thanks all in advance!

Comment: Are you making up your own tag names, or is `desc1` in HTML 5 somewhere?

Comment: You can use jquery fadein too

Comment: http://www.graphicfusiondesign.com/blog/design/creating-fancy-css3-fade-in-animations-on-page-load/  search for "css3 fade in animation"

Comment: @WaleedKhan yes, i put it in my CSS, how you can see. I use the ID "spoiler". works perfectly. my problem is only the transition.

Comment: How do you trigger the transition? I don't see any change "from" to "to"

Comment: @btevfik I like use the CSS for transitions.

Comment: @Manoel Do *not* use custom tags. Use `div`s or `span`s with custom classes instead.

Comment: @WaleedKhan But my custom tags work perfectly. Do you think the problem of the transition may be because of them?

Comment: @Manoel No, but your HTML isn't valid as you have it. Just because they work doesn't mean you should use them.

Comment: @MichaelSazonov I trigger by the <div> ID. But still don't work.

Comment: Please see here the code without transition: http://jsfiddle.net/3JJr8/1/
It's all right, but i can't make a fade transition when click in "See the phrases"
If I use hover, works, look: http://jsfiddle.net/3JJr8/7/
What I can do?

Answer (score 0):

Use javascript to add a class to the spoiler, CSS3 to animate but understand the browsers that don't use CSS3.

```
#spoiler {
opacity:0;
-webkit-transition: all .8s ease-in;
-moz-transition: all .8s ease-in;
-o-transition: all .8s ease-in;
-ms-transition: all .8s ease-in;
 transition: all .8s ease-in;
}

#spoiler.show {
opacity:1;
}
```

With a browser that doesn't support css3, I use Modernizr + jQuery for the fallback.

```
if (!Modernizr.csstransitions) { // if browser doesn't support css3.transitions
  $('#spoiler').animate({ "opacity": '1' }, 800);
} else { // if browser does support css3.transitions
  $('#spoiler').addClass('show');
}
```